# MOSS 2007 Sharepoint Shared Services AD Import SQL/Search Error prevents user import

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-services

When attempting to import new AD users (Shared Services Administration > Shared Service > User Profiles and Properties) I receive an error on the top of the User Profiles and Properties page.

***"An error has occurred while accessing the SQL Server database or the Office SharePoint Server Search service. If this is the first time you have seen this message, try again later. If this problem persists, contact your administrator."***

I have tried the following:

1. Rebooted server
2. Checked service account permissions and passwords
3. Checked the MIPSCHEDULEDJOB table to ensure all 6 required entries are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply built a new SSP.